# How to access USB (Pen Drive) Firmware Number from Delphi or VB6?

Tags: delphi, usb, usb-drive

I want to access/read the Firmware Number of a Pendrive attached on a USB Port of a PC.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

After hunting around for a little while I found the following links which may point you in the right direction.

1. [Alan Macek](http://www.alanmacek.com/usb/)
2. [USB-IF Developers Area](http://www.usb.org/developers)

*Edit*: Mind you, you could just consult the Registry, which also stores info re the currently connected USB device. See [Tracing USB Devices on XP](http://scissec.scis.ecu.edu.au/conference_proceedings/2007/forensics/23_Luo_Tracing_USB_Device_artefacts_on_Windows_XP.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

this is 100% protocol/vendor dependent. There is an option to add version information to standard usb device descriptors, but assuming that every usb pen will use same mechanism is wrong.